# Django rest framework simple-jwt error "detail": "No active account found with the given credentials"

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, jwt, django-rest-framework-simplejwt

I created a custom user model in Django and am using djangorestframework simplejwt for the authentication (login and signup).

models:

```
class UserAccountManager(BaseUserManager):
    def create_user(self, email, name, password=None):
        if not email:
            raise ValueError('Users must have unique email address')

        email = self.normalize_email(email)
        user = self.model(email=email, name=name)

        user.set_password(password)
        user.save()

        return user

    def create_superuser(self, email, name, password):
        user = self.create_user(email, name, password)

        user.is_superuser = True
        user.is_staff = True
        user.save()

        return user

class UserAccount(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=255, unique=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    objects = UserAccountManager()

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['name']

    def get_full_name(self):
        return self.name

    def get_short_name(self):
        return self.name

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email
```

I can signup just fine but when I try to login (using postman for this),  it shows the following message:

```
{
    "detail": "No active account found with the given credentials"
}
```

all my credentials were accurate and I have checked through the python shell that my users are all active and had the right email~password. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you registered the custom user model in the `settings.py` file?

Comment: Yes the app is registered and also is in the AUTH_USER_MODEL

Answer (score 0):

Use your superuser credentials to see if it's working

Comment: this really should be a comment

Answer (score 0):

You should create new superuser account after setting up JWT authentication